# How to debug a productFlavor in Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea

If one changes the packageName for a specific productFlavor, how does he debug and set breakpoint for this flavor?

By checking the box "Show all processes" in Android Studio (v0.6.1), I can see the flavored application.

But then, I get:

> Error running Android Debugger (8602): Unable to open debugger port : java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"

Answer (score 0):

Set `debuggable` to true in your flavor:

```
buildTypes{
   flavor {
       debuggable true
   }
}
```

By default it is false for flavours except debug (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide)

Comment: I know, but the debuggable is already set in the BuildType, not the Product Flavor. The application is debuggable but is not recognised by the IDE to be debuggable. I guess because the package does not bind to any application's package loaded in the IDE.

Comment: So do you see app in the list on the left side in "Android" pane?

Comment: Yes. I updated the question, I see the app if I check the box, but it can't connect to the flavor while it works for the flavor that has the same package name than the manifest in the source